# Multiple DIVs centeralized in a single row

Tags: css

below is my code, the thumb Divs are starting from left but how can I make them centralized?

```css
.thumbsPanel {
 border: thin black dashed;
 width: 800px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;

}
.thumbs {

 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 0;
 margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbsPanel">
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="1.html"><img src="1.jpg"></a></div>
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="2.html"><img src="2.jpg"></a></div>
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="3.html"><img src="3.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much point in floating the divs if you want to center them. Instead make them inline-block elements and use text-align:center on the parent:

```css
.thumbsPanel {
  border: thin black dashed;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.thumbs {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbsPanel">
  <div class="thumbs">
    <a href="1.html">
      <img src="1.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
    <a href="2.html">
      <img src="2.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
    <a href="3.html">
      <img src="3.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite method is to add a `text-align: center;` to the parent element, then use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`

```css
.thumbsPanel {
 border: thin black dashed;
 width: 800px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

}
.thumbs {

 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 0;
 margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbsPanel">
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="1.html"><img src="1.jpg"></a></div>
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="2.html"><img src="2.jpg"></a></div>
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="3.html"><img src="3.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline-block to thumbs instead of float left like:

```css
.thumbsPanel {
 border: thin black dashed;
 width: 800px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;

}
.thumbs {
  display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbsPanel">
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="1.html">a</a></div>
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="2.html">b</a></div>
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="3.html">c</a></div>
</div>
```

If you want to conserve your floating behavior you should add an container to your thumbs, also using float dont forget to clearfix the container like:

```css
.thumbsPanel {
 border: thin black dashed;
 width: 800px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

}
.thumbsWrap {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbs {
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbsPanel">
  <div class="thumbsWrap"> 
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="1.html">a</a></div>
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="2.html">b</a></div>
 <div class="thumbs"><a href="3.html">c</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```